# Save the selected item and use it in another page

Tags: android, visual-studio, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Mobile App in Xamarin.Forms. I have "visitedDoctor" page and a listview in this page. I want to see the selected doctor in main page but I can't transfer the selected item to main page. What should I use to do this ?

Comment: Your description of your app structure is incredibly vague.  Generally speaking there are many different ways you could approach this.  You could use MessagingCenter to pass the value between pages.  You could create a property on your App class to store the value.  You could use a singleton VM to store app-wide values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass data between two page, you can also do this by constructor, I do one sample about pass ListView's selecteditem to another page.

VisitedDoctor.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding doctors}" SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding address}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
            Text="go to mainpage" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

To get selecteditem, don't forget to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface to notify data changed.

```
 public partial class visitedDoctor : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<doctor> doctors { get; set; }
    private doctor _selecteditem;
    public doctor selecteditem
    {
        get { return _selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selecteditem");
        }
    }
    public visitedDoctor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        doctors = new ObservableCollection<doctor>()
        {
            new doctor(){name="doctor 1",address="address 1"},
            new doctor(){name="doctor 2",address="address 2"},
            new doctor(){name="doctor 3",address="address 3"},
            new doctor(){name="doctor 4",address="address 4"}

        };
        selecteditem = doctors[0];
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private async void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage(selecteditem));
    }
}
public class doctor
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(doctor d)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Console.WriteLine("the selected doctor is {0}",d.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MessagingCenter` class to send objects between pages:

To send a message use the `MessagingCenter.Send` method - to subscribe - use the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` method:

Here's an example of sending a string between two pages:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string> (this, "Hi", "John");
```

Now MainPage needs to **subscribe:**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string> (this, "Hi", (sender, arg) => {
    // do whatever
});
```

You can adapt this code however you would like.